# HTL -how to display a page on another page like popup / modal

Tags: adobe, aem, sightly, htl

I'm trying to use existing page (selected with pathbrowser from TouchUI) as a popup / modal on my HTL page. Is there a way of adding / injecting HTML from different file using sightly ? 
It's more about sightly and rendering that html on the page rather then how to build dialogue window.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you need is to include the content (not the template) within your page, preferrably using `data-sly-resource` with the path of your page (/content/myapp/content/myPageIwantToDisplayAsModal). this will render the relevant html on your page - remember that in AEM the content knows how to display itself - so as said above you only need to reference the content

Probably you could also utilise the use of selectors not to display the whole html along with `<head>` section and unneeded `<body>` tag

so for example:

`<div data-sly-resource="${'/content/myapp/content/myPageIwantToDisplayAsModal' @ selectors=['content']}"></div>`

for referrence go here https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/htl/docs/block-statements.html

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to use reference component and inject the HTML of the referenced page. Then you could wrap/style it as a popup using JS/CSS magic.

Comment: I'm looking at <sly data-sly-include="path/to/template.html"></sly> but that don't seems to work.. popup is not a problem (css and js) just how to inject html code

Comment: use data-sly-resource rather than include